# InvalidCastException when invoking PropertyChangedEventHandler

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, dependency-properties, inotifypropertychanged

**Situation**:

- UWP app using MVVM and Xaml for UI
- View Models are derived from a `ModelBase` class implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface

**Problem**:

- when executing a specific UI test using the affected class, in some cases the application throws an `InvalidCastException` during the `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))` call. The propertyName is set correctly using the [CallerMemberName] which was verified using a debug log entry. The `SetProperty` method is called in the DependencyProperty with a backing field. A DebugConverter used in the Xaml element which is bound to the PropertyChanged event shows a valid conversion but the setting of the bound element fails. It looks like a Double to Double cast is not possible which makes no sense.

**Question**

- Does anyone have an idea what the reason for this exception could be?

**Code**

Control.xaml

```
Maximum="{Binding TimeControlCanvasWidth, Converter={StaticResource DebugConverter}}" />
```

ModelBase.cs

```
public class ModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The event raised, when the property changed
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        try
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        catch (System.InvalidCastException)
        {
            LogManager.Current.GetLogger(GetType()).LogCritical(() => $"#####{nameof(OnPropertyChanged)}" +
                $" - InvalidCastException | propertyName={propertyName}");
        }
    }

    protected virtual bool SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (field?.Equals(value) == true)
        {
            return false;
        }

        field = value;

        // ReSharper disable once ExplicitCallerInfoArgument
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

ViewModel.cs

```
public class TimeControlViewModel : ModelBase 
{ 
    private double _timeControlCanvasWidth;

    public double TimeControlCanvasWidth
    {
        get => _timeControlCanvasWidth;
        set
        {
             if (SetProperty(ref _timeControlCanvasWidth, value))
             {
                // do sth.
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any chance that the property name at OnPropertyChanged() is null?  Per the documentation, when constructor for PropertyChangedEventArgs() gets a null value, it then indicates that all of the properties have changed.  In this case, some of the current property value backing fields may have values that may cause your issue.

Comment: In case the ```InvalidCastException``` occurs, the log entry always looks like ```#####OnPropertyChanged - InvalidCastException | propertyName=TimeControlCanvasWidth``` which does not indicate that the passed property name is null.

Comment: I have had something like this happen when I use an integer as the default value in the PropertyMetadata rather than a double.  That is, the number I use does not have a decimal point that specifically identifies the number as a double (i.e. 50 rather than 50.0)